# How to check Oracle internal process?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, oracle11g, oracle10g

I want to know what oracle internal process is running for the below session details.

How to check what process is being carried out by "**ora_j001**" ?
Please provide me query to find out the process ?

```
INST_ID SID SERIAL# USERNAME    OSUSER  MACHINE PROCESS OS Process ID   VALUE   STATUS  LAST_CALL_ET    PROGRAM
1          1303 13000    APPS   orafin  ARG-FIN1A-DC    3842124 3842124 224905256   ACTIVE  57661   oracle@ARG-FIN1A-DC (J001)



$ ps -ef | grep 3842124
  orafin 3842124       1   0 18:24:54      -  2:02 ora_j001_FINPROD1
  argora 4395248 4784358   0 10:41:08  pts/6  0:00 grep 3842124
$ hostname
ARG-FIN1A-DC
```

In such kind of process how to check whether what kind of oracle internal process is running ?

Comment: What mean you by - oracle internal process?

Comment: Check `v$process`. According to [**the manual**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/process.htm#BABDECGE) the Jxxx processes belong to the job queue

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Is there any way to find what these internal process are processing ? If yes, then kindly provide a query to find out.    Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You have listed your SID there. This will find the current SQL being run by any SID.  Tie this back to DBA_JOBS or DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS to see job related activity.

```
select q.sql_text, q.piece from V$SQLTEXT_WITH_NEWLINES
where q.SQL_ID = <SID>
order by 2;
```